# Duplicate does not already have an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, duplicate-questions

When looking at a duplicate question on the Android app, it says

> This question already has an answer here

and then a link follows to the question of which the current is a duplicate.

However, as shown in the picture below, this does also show for questions of which the duplicate has no answers! This can get horribly confusing.

> [image: Duplicate does not have an answer]

<sub>P.S.: Could not show my awesome paint skills with red lines and such as I am on the app.</sub>

Comment: Maybe it could say "This question has already been asked here:"?

Comment: It should say "*This question is an exact duplicate of*" just like the website counterpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

When the target question has zero answers, it will read "This question is an exact duplicate of:"